# I am having difficulties in converting a string to array in php

Tags: php

I have a javascript code that sends a data to my php file...

a sample value of this is:

```
array(
   array('story_name'=>'mystory', 'priority'=>1),
   array('story_name'=>'mystory2', 'priority'=>2)
)
```

so my question is how can i convert this string into the same format of php array so that i can append this to my queries?

Comment: is there a reason for using *this* format instead of a standard one? (like JSON)

Comment: You can not send array into php via JS. Only string in some format (like JSON for example).

Comment: yeah thats a string not an actual array.. i did use escape(thestringArray) to send it to my php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON:

```
echo json_encode($yourarray);
echo json_decode($_GET['fromjs']);
```

Comment: You could serialize() then urlencode() it but json_encode is better in every way (smaller, more readable, more portable...)

Comment: the problem is those arrays is just a string and not an array structure, still json can do that?

Comment: Convert it to an array. Why using a string anyway here... Is there a reason for it has to be a string there? I makes no sense to me ;) Work with array structure in js and convert it to a JSON string for interaction with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to send native php code to the server? That can really cause some ***major*** security holes. It's much better to send data in a much more php friendly format.

```
mystory,1|mystory,2
```

Then you can just use the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method to convert the data into arrays

Others have suggested using JSON. You would format your above data as follows in JSON

```
[       //Used to indicate sequential array i.e. $myarray[0]
    {   //Used to indicate associative array i.e. $myarray["story_name"]
        story_name: "mystory",
        priority: 1
    },
    {
        story_name: "mystory2",
        priority: 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The javascript array values can be passed to a php file using the following method

Step 1:

Let us consider we have a js array as

```
<script language=javascript>
scriptAr = new Array();
scriptAr[0] = "one";
scriptAr[1] = "two";
scriptAr[2] = "three";
<script>
```

Step 2:

```
Now we will create a hidden form field as follows
<form action="phpArrayTest.php" method=post name=test onSubmit=setValue()>
<input name=arv type=hidden>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Here what we have done is, when the submit is called we first do some work ("onSubmit=setValue()") by using the onSubmit method. The onSubmit method will invoke setValue() function defined by us. After that the action will take place and stringTokens.php will be called.

Step 3:
Here we define the setValue method. The method will convert the array periviously defined in to a string and then set it to the hidden field.

```
<script language=javascript>    

function setValue()
{
var arv = scriptAr.toString();
// This line converts js array to String document.test.arv.value=arv;
// This sets the string to the hidden form field. }
</script>
```

Step 4:
In the php file the string will be split back into array.

From http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/php/jsArrayToPHP.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval:

```
$arr = eval($data);
```

Note that this could result in security problems since eval() executes any PHP code from a string. You should use this with cauntion.

You also need to add a return to your code.

More information on eval() can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

The better way would be to send JSON to your php script like this:

In javascript:

```
var json = array2json(YOUR_JS_ARRAY);
```

Send this to your PHP script and there decode this to a PHP array like this:

```
json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for more information on JSON decode.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for more information on the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).